# How do I add a dynamic marker or pin to a ArcGIS Runtime shared map app with xamarin forms on visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary, xamarin.forms, arcgis-runtime-net

I am working on a cross platform app that will display a map and allow a user to place a marker/pin (whichever you want to call it) on the map. I have already managed to display the map on my device so this is fine. However I do not know how to add the markers/pins.
Please try and keep it simple as I am a beginner.

My code is simply the default ArcGIS runtime App (Xamarin.Forms Shared) code so I don't think it needs to be show, but if you need it please ask for it. Thanks!